# Can't see membership sign-up page!

Tags: civimember, contribution-page, forms

In Joomla, I've created a membership sign-up page under contribution pages. If I click "Test-drive" I can see the form and everything seems ok, but If I click "live page" or the corresponding menu entry (Associati) I receive error 0. I've noticed that the URL seems wrong, because the item ID is 1, not 1035 and if I correct it, I get the site interface, but no form anyway. Can someone help me? Even paying! maybe you need only to access administrator panel and give a fast look.... It's very important...

Thank you

http://www.lamuccapazza.org/

Comment: Can you paste the paths for live v test - and compare them with the Demo site at http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: http://www.lamuccapazza.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1&action=preview

http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/contribute/transact&id=2&action=preview&reset=1